# Cordova SQLite transaction data not persistent

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cordova

I'm to dump, to store persistent data in a sqlite database, with the cordova-sqlite-plugin. Everytime I reload the browser, started per: "cordova emulate browser", the written data is gone. Same when I start the android emulator per: "cordova emulate android". In the android emulator, i have to restart and reopen the app, to repruduce the problem.
I tried various things, to fix this issue:

1. Add various database.close() parts. See the uncommented parts in the javascript code. Everytime I do this, I get the following messages in the browser javascript console: "database was closed during open operation" and "cannot start next transaction: database not open"
2. I checked if the data relay written, see the console.log parts below the inserts or updates.
3. Added the "androidDatabaseProvider" in the database.open part
4. etc. etc.

Here the javascript code:

```
var database = null;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
  database = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'fts-running.sqlite', location: 'default', androidDatabaseProvider: 'system', androidLockWorkaround: 1});
  initDatabase();
  showIntruduction();
  // database.close();
});

function successcb(){
  console.log('INFO: Database opened succesfully!')
}

function errorcb(){
  console.log('ERROR: Database open failed!')
}

function initDatabase() {
  console.log('INFO: initDatabase started!');

  database.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS running_current_run (run_id bigint PRIMARYKEY, run_start_datetime datetime, run_end_datetime datetime)');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS running_history (run_id bigint PRIMARYKEY, run_total_distance float, run_average_pace bigint, run_average_speed float, run_start_datetime datetime, run_end_datetime datetime)');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS running_geodata (run_id bigint PRIMARYKEY, run_coordinate_latitude float, run_coordinate_longitude float, run_current_datetime datetime)');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS running_settings (intruduction_viewed boolean)');
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM running_settings', [], function(tx, rs) {
      if(rs.rows.length == 0) {
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO running_settings (intruduction_viewed) VALUES (false)', [], function(tx, rs) {
          console.log('rs.insertId: ' + rs.insertId);
          console.log('rs.rowsAffected: ' + rs.rowsAffected);
        }, function(tx, error) {
          console.log('INSERT error: ' + error.message);
        });
      }
    });
  }, function(error) {
    console.log('transaction error: ' + error.message);
  }, function() {
    console.log('transaction ok');
  });
}

function showIntruduction() {
  console.log('INFO: showIntruduction started!');

  database.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT intruduction_viewed FROM running_settings', [], function(tx, rs) {
      if(rs.rows.item(0).intruduction_viewed == false || rs.rows.item(0).intruduction_viewed == null) {
        var element = document.getElementById('intruduction_wrapper');
        element.style.display = "block";
      }
    });
  }, function(error) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' + error.message);
  }, function() {
    console.log('INFO: showIntruduction finished!');
  });
}

function set_intruduction_viewed() {
  console.log('INFO: set_intruduction_viewed started!');
  // database = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'fts-running.db', location: 'default'});

  database.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('UPDATE running_settings SET intruduction_viewed = true WHERE intruduction_viewed = false', [], function(tx, rs) {
      var element = document.getElementById('intruduction_wrapper');
      element.style.display = "none";
      console.log('rs.insertId: ' + rs.insertId);
      console.log('rs.rowsAffected: ' + rs.rowsAffected);
    }, function(tx, error) {
      console.log('Update error: ' + error.message);
    });
  }, function(error) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' + error.message);
  }, function() {
    console.log('INFO: set_intruduction_viewed finished!');
  });
  // database.close();
}
```

Here my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/globalstyle.css"></link>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage/www/SQLitePlugin.js"></script>
        <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="intruduction_wrapper">
        <div id="intruduction_text">Hallo</div>
        <button id="confirmation" onclick="set_intruduction_viewed()" type="button">Confirm</button>
      </div>

      <div class="snap-wrapper">
        <div class="snap-items section-one">
          <div id="run_propperties">
              <div id="top_section"></div>
              <div id="mid_section_left"></div>
              <div id="mid_section_right"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="bottom">
            <button class="button" id="start_run" type="button" onclick="">Start action</button>
            <div class="dots">
              <span class="dot" id="dot1"></span>
              <span class="dot" id="dot2"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="snap-items section-two">
          <div class="bottom">
            <div class="dots">
              <span class="dot" id="dot3"></span>
              <span class="dot" id="dot4"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Here my css:

```
body,html,.snap-wrapper,.snap-items {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#intruduction_wrapper {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#intruduction_text  {
  height: 95vh;
  width: 95vw;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#confirmation {
  
}

.snap-wrapper {
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.snap-items {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  min-width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#run_propperties {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#top_section {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10vh;
}

.bottom {
  margin-top: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 5vh;
  margin-bottom: 1vh;
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
}

.button:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: grey;
}

.dot {
 margin-left: 0.5vw;
 height: 12px;
 width: 12px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-bottom: 1vh;
}

.section-one span:nth-of-type(1)  {
  background-color: black;
}

.section-one span:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.section-two span:nth-of-type(1)  {
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.section-two span:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: black;
}
```

I searched alot, to fix this issue by my self, this is my last hope, to fix it. I am very thankfull for all your messages and your help!

Regards
Jonas

Comment: I’m not a JavaScript guy but have used SQLite a good bit. I expect you need to add a tx.comit() call after your update and insert statements.

Comment: You are calling 'showIntroduction()' immediately after 'initDatabase()'. Surely the Sql transactions called in the frist won't have completed when the second is called. I think you need to wait until the callback function (function(tx, rs)) completes before doing more Sql tarnsactions - i.e. move any subsequent sql operations into the first callback.

Comment: Thanks for your comments!! I moved the showInstruction part now in the success of the initDatabase function. I get the success message from both function, but the data isn't stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to at a callback and error function, in the database open part. After I added the functions everything works for me.
Here the functional openDatabase part:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
  database = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'fts-running.db', location: 'default', androidDatabaseProvider: 'system', androidLockWorkaround: 1}, function(db) {
    console.log('Database opend succesfully!');
    initDatabase();
    // showIntruduction();
  }, function(error) {
    console.log('Open database ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
  });
});
```